# How to add Angular project to Django and Docker

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, docker

I would like to add Angular 4 project to Docker with Django project? My structure of files look in this way:
`DockerContainer`:

```
Backend                 
Dockerfile              
Frontend                
docker-compose.yml      
requirements.txt
```

I would like to create Angular 4 project in `Frontend` directory. I can do this using `ng new my-app` but what should I do next? This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 Backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

At the moment structure of my files in main directory with your suggestions look in this way:

```
├── Backend
│   ├── AI
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── manage.py
├── Dockerfile
├── Frontend
│   └── angularProject
│       └── all files in my angular project 
├── docker-compose.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

Comment: Your question is likely being voted closed as too broad because "what should I do next?" is open to interpretation. There are many ways to answer that question as it is stated. I'll try to answer the question if it were "How to build a Angular 4 Docker image and serve the application".

Answer (score 0):

Angular 4 projects are just HTML and JavaScript (from what I understand). Generally, we would build the application and then serve it from a web server (such as nginx for Apache HTTPD). I decided to make an example of an Angular 4 Docker image based on a recent Docker feature for multi-stage builds.

The example is at https://gist.github.com/andyshinn/de65b71a7b50a0e5a73732c69f1a3d35. Assuming your Angular 4 application code root was at `Frontend`, you would copy this `Dockerfile` and `nginx.conf` to the `Frontend` folder. Then, you can add a new service to your `docker-compose.yml` to build and run it. Here is an example of that addition:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 Backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  angular:
    build: Frontend/angularProject
    ports:
      - "8010:80"
    depends_on:
      - django
```

Comment: I get `ERROR: Service 'angular' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder079901171/package.json: no such file or directory
`

Comment: Then there is no `package.json` in the `Frontend` folder. Is your Angular project in that folder or another one?

Comment: I have updated my first post with structure of files.

Comment: I have updated the `build` path in Docker Compose based on your tree. The path should be to where the `Dockerfile` and `package.json` lives.

Comment: Everything works fine. Why do you suggest and use nginx?

Comment: I only used it as example because I know it well and there is a small official Docker image for it. But it should be possible to use any webserver.

Comment: Can't I just use it on localhost without nginx?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure what you mean though. Maybe you should open a new question about that.